# HTML <button> onclick not working inside <form> tag

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently building an ASP.NET MVC application and I was wondering what the reason might be for a button onclick function not to work inside the form tag. I want this button to be type="button" and not "submit". Also, none of the inputs are bound to any model attribute. The whole purpose of this application is to serve as a mockup template for my customer. The buttons onclick actions are calling controller actions that I have created that do nothing but return the view. I have the same setup on other Views and the buttons work as expected but for some reason these button don't do anything when clicked. I even copy and pasted code from other Views that I know work and still nothing. Not sure what is going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!  Here is some sample code:

**CSHTML:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
            <h3>WORK LOCATION INFO</h3>
            <hr />
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="input-label" for="locationType">This is a:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="locationType">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>All location types</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="input-label" for="campus">Campus <small><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></small></label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="campus">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>All campuses</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="input-label" for="location">Location <small><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></small></label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="location">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>All Locations</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-blue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("WorkPosition", "RosterAdmin")'"><strong>GO BACK</strong></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-green" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateProfile", "RosterAdmin")'"><strong>CONTINUE</strong></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class RosterAdminController : Controller
{
    // GET: RosterAdmin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult WorkPosition()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult WorkLocation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateProfile()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you modified the asp.net mvc default route?

Comment: Nope, I have left the RouteConfig alone. I'm not savvy enough with MVC yet to start messing that up, lol

Comment: Are your URL's generating correctly? What happens if you hit the URL's directly?

Comment: I can manually type in the URL and it navigates to the page correctly.  If I run the dev tools the links for the buttons show the correct URL as well.

Comment: Can you post the rendered button html?

Comment: Certainly,

`<button class="btn btn-default button-green" onclick="location.href='/RosterAdmin/CreateProfile'" type="button"><strong>CONTINUE</strong></button>`

Comment: the same format appears for the "GO BACK" button.

Comment: Does it work if you use `window.location.href`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil wow! it does indeed!

Comment: why would that make a difference since location.href works on other pages except for this one?

Comment: also, @stephen.vakil please write your suggestion in an answer so I can mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across

Comment: Thanks, @mxmissile ! much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `location` is being set to something else somewhere in your scripts.  Generally, it is safer to use `window.location` to avoid issues like this.  If you change your buttons to use `window.location.href` instead, it likely will work.

You could attempt to debug this issue in the browser to determine where `location` is being altered if you want to avoid this elsewhere in your code.

See: [Is there any difference with using only location vs using window.location across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across)