# location.href require window.location.href on some pages

Tags: javascript

Why is it that some pages in my web project works simply by using `location.href` in the `onclick` function while some require me to enter `window.location.href` for redirection to work.
I've read out the `scope` related aspects related to using `window`. prefix to `location.href` but I'm still unable to comprehend this fully.

Any information on this will be highly appreciable.

Cheers!

Comment: it will varies based on the context. Refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903659/difference-between-window-location-and-location-href

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that would make `location.href` not work when `window.location.href` does work is if you've *shadowed* the `location` identifier by declaring one in a nearer scope than the global one, like this:

```
location.href = "..."; // would work here...
function foo() {
    var location = 42;
    location.href = "..."; // ...but not here

    function bar() {
        location.href = "..."; // ...nor here
    }

    bar();
}
foo();
```