# What is the difference between window.location.hash and location.hash?

Tags: javascript

I often see `window.location.hash` and `location.hash` (hash here being a sample) referenced in various Javascripts. What is the difference between those calls (that seem to me have identical results).

Comment: check this one - its the same question (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is the global object in the browser, so unqualified, undeclared names are looked up on it by default. As such, `window.location` and `location` mean the exact same thing unless a scoped variable named `location` has been declared.

Comment: @Kinduser: Eh. I answered before any duplicates were linked. No point in deleting when it's not wrong/misleading.

Comment: It's not misleading/wrong, I agree, but moderators are deleting questions/answers for even more trivial reasons nowadays...