# Dynamically Creating Filename for Button OnClick

Tags: dynamic, onclick, filenames

I have a family tree website and want to show all events in our family on the current date (Month and Day). So, if today's April 3rd, I want to show all events in our family that occurred on April 3rd.

I've played with creating a table and hiding rows, etc. but the table's too big and it's taking too long. So, I've decided to create a separate .htm file for each day of the year (i.e., todayinhistory-0101.htm, todayinhistory-0102.htm, etc.).

I have a button which, when clicked, is to get the current date in MMDD format and then open the correct file.

I have the script to get the correct filename using the current date in MMDD format, but I can't figure out how to call it and make it work.

Right now, my button looks like this:

```
<button onclick="location='GetTodayInHistoryFilename()'">
```

GetTodayInHistoryFilename() is a function I know works. I just can't get the button format right to call it.

Obviously, I'm a novice and would appreciate anyone's help.

In case you're interested, here's GetTodayInHistoryFilename() - which is loaded in the page's header section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function GetTodayInHistoryFilename()
     {
         var Today = new Date();
         var TodayMonth = Today.getMonth()+1;
         var TodayDay = Today.getDate();
         if (TodayMonth < 10) { TodayMonth = '0' + String(TodayMonth); } else { TodayMonth = String(TodayMonth); }
         if (TodayDay < 10) { TodayDay = '0' + String(TodayDay); } else { TodayDay = String(TodayDay); }
         return 'todayinhistory-' + TodayMonth + TodayDay + '.htm';
     }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're trying to do but I think you want the button click to navigate to another HTML page in which case - you're not far off:

```
<button onclick="window.location=GetTodayInHistoryFilename()">
```

Explanation: You're setting the location property of the window object (your browser's top level frame, in this case) to *(a new url)*. You've defined this using your function which is fine. The only mistake you made was to include the function in quotes. This meant that function name was treated as a literal text string rather than an executable function.

You may or may not need to specify `window.` (the global object) in `window.location`. I wasn't sure myself but it's nicely answered here: [window.location versus just location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location)